# I want to use DoubleBuffered method on my Datagridview to make the scrolling smoother

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to make my datagridview look better when scrolling because it looks like I'm using a pc from 2000 or worse. While searching I came across the method DoubleBuffered that everyone says makes things better.

When I use it, dataGridView2.DoubleBuffered(true) line goes red with error message: CS1955  C# Non-invocable member cannot be used like a method. Cannot access protected property 'DoubleBuffered' here.

If you can't help me with the error, maybe tell a way to make scrolling smoother.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Reflection;

namespace WarehouseManagementToolv1
{
    public partial class OrdersForm : Form
    {

        public SecondaryCallDB.GetDatabase _GetDatabase;
        private OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();

        public OrdersForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); 
            _GetDatabase = new SecondaryCallDB.GetDatabase();
        }

        private void btnLoadTable_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView2.DataSource = _GetDatabase.GetFullOrderDatabase();
            dataGridView2.DoubleBuffered(true);
        }

        public void DoubleBuffered(DataGridView dgv, bool setting)
        {
            Type dgvType = dgv.GetType();
            PropertyInfo pi = dgvType.GetProperty("DoubleBuffered",
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            pi.SetValue(dgv, setting, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably mean `DoubleBuffered(dataGridView2, true)`. It's not extension method.

Comment: `DoubleBuffered` is the name of Property of your Form. Maybe change the method name to, say, `SetDoubleBuffered`. You should really remove this: `private OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();`. If you need to open a connection, open and dispose of it in-place. Don't try to *cache* it. You don't have any hope of good performance when you use a connection object as a field.

Comment: Then, make sure you don't have any Cell *formatting* procedure that loops the full content of the DGV's DataSource. Use the appropriate events (`CellFormatting`, `RowPrePaint` etc)

Answer (score 1):

You should either place this method inside a static class and turn it into an extension method by doing the following

```
public static void DoubleBuffered(this DataGridView dgv, bool setting)
        {
            Type dgvType = dgv.GetType();
            PropertyInfo pi = dgvType.GetProperty("DoubleBuffered",
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            pi.SetValue(dgv, setting, null);
        }
```

Or you should call the method like a normal method which it is.

```
DoubleBuffered(dataGridView2, true)
```

Comment: well.. i was just calling it the wrong way, thanks! it works fine now!